# C#: Find All Members under Multiple Classes with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

We have a API Response Body, which can contain multiple Documents. Within class `Documents`, there are multiple `Properties` with PropertyIds.

How do I get a list of All the PropertiesIds within all Documents? Is SelectMany with Select the proper way? This seems to be working below, just want to validate

```
var result = response.Body.Documents?.SelectMany(x=>x.Properties).Select(x=>x.PropertyId)
```

Note: when trying to SelectManys, gives error below,

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany(IEnumerable, Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Another option would be `response.Body.Documents?.SelectMany(x=>x.Properties.Select(z => z.PropertyId))`. I think your way is better though, less Method calls than my example.

Comment: Your code seems correct, but would need to see the structure of `Documents` class, the `Properties` and `PropertyId` to be sure of the answer you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two selectMany

try this

```
var result = response.Body.Documents?.SelectMany(x=>x.Properties.SelectMany(j=>j.PropertyId))
```

Comment: Sorry I put second selectmany in wrong position, my response is edited, try now.